# A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am trying to validate email domain validation using the following code (Found on Code Proejct)

```
string hostName="<hostName>"; //Ex: yahoo.com
IPHostEntry Iphost=Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
IPEndPoint endPt=new IPEndPoint(Iphost.AddressList[0],25);
Socket s=new Socket(endPt.AdressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

s.Connect(endPt);
```

At s.Connect  I am getting the error: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.
What might be the possible reasons and how can I resolve them? I have Firewall (Comodo) on my machine.

Comment: The only reason would be that the network is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

The computer is not able to connect to the address that was resolved.

Look at the address you were given by `Dns.Resolve`.

> **Note:** The `Resolve` method [is obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.resolve.aspx), and replaced with GetHostEntry. e.g.:
>
> ```
> IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("yahoo.com");
> ```

Comment: Updated my question.My mistake I just copied the code but I did use Dns.GetHostEntry("<hostName>") in my actual code. What things do I need to check to make my computer to connect to the address that was resolved? I tried gmail.com, hotmail.com host names also but still the same error.

Comment: @MNVR: that's not a programming question. You should ask on SuperUser instead.